# Python: there is a 'NameError' with a object variable when the variable is called by a class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a program with a grid in it, and I need a 2d array.  In the constructor for the `Grid` object, I initialize 2 variables, a `tuple` that holds coordinates, and a 2d array of objects.  The `tuple(Named, selected)` works perfectly.  The array(named `gridArray`) does not work as intended.

When I run the program when the method `selectCell` is called I get the error 
`"NameError: name 'gridArray' is not defined"`

To test it I have turned `gridArray` into a simple int, and the program gives the same error.  I have also called it with the following:

`Grid.gridArray`
This gives the error that Grid array doesn't have a variable named `gridArray`

`self.gridArray`
The error essentially says `self` isn't defined.

Code:

```
class Grid:
    def _init_(self):
        gridArray = 5      #[[cell.Cell() for j in range(9)] for i in range(9)]
        selected = (-1,-1)

    def selectCell(x):
        selected = (int(x[0]/const.CELLSIZE),int(x[1]/const.CELLSIZE))
        print(selected)
        print(gridArray)
```

`print(gridArray)` should just print 5 instead, it is just a `NameError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to the `gridArray` attribute of a *specific instance*. This is often done with `self`, and is necessary to distinguish between class variables, instance variables and local variables:

```
class Grid:

    # Class variables are defined here. All instances of the class share references to them.

    def __init__(self):
        # Anything prefixed with "self" is an instance variable. There will be one for each instance of Grid.
        # Anything without is a local variable. There will be one for each time the function is called.
        self.gridArray = 5
        self.selected = (-1, -1)

    def selectCell(self, x):
        self.selected = (int(x[0] / const.CELLSIZE),int(x[1] / const.CELLSIZE))
        print(self.selected)
        print(self.gridArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every function in a class needs to parse the `self` variable for it to reference other variables defined in the instance of the class when it's created. Right now, gridArray is a local variable in your `__init__` function. You can read more about classes here https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

You should define `gridArray` as `self.gridArray` so that you can use it other places in your class. Be sure to also parse the `self` variable in every function that belongs to a class like this: `def selectCell(self, x):` the general format is `def <funcname>(self, *args): <code>`.

Also, the `__init__` function should have 2 underscores before and after.